# Login Validation from parsed result

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I've successfully parsed an result from a SOAP WebServices request I made, by sending in a userName and password.

But now I need to validate this login function and if true segue to a new view programmatically:

```
let menuPageView =  (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuCentral"))!
self.present(menuPageView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem is I don't know how or where to add such validation.

```
    class LoginCentralViewController: UIViewController, SOAPServiceProtocol {
        var chave = ChaveWebService().chave()
        var soapService : SOAPService?
        var resultadoLoginCentral : [LoginCentralModel]!


        @IBOutlet weak var txtUsuarioOUTLET: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var txtSenhaOUTLET: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var btnAcessarOUTLET: UIButton!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            soapService = SOAPService(delegate: self)

            print(chave)


        }

        @IBAction func btnAcessarACTION(_ sender: Any) {
            soapService?.loginCentral(userName: txtUsuarioOUTLET.text!, password: txtSenhaOUTLET.text!, methodName: nomeServico)

            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true


        }



        func didSuccessRequest(results: XMLIndexer, requestName: String) {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

            switch requestName {
            case nomeServico:
                do{
                    resultadoLoginCentral = try LoginCentralModel.realizarLoginCentral(results: results)

                } catch let error as XMLParseError{
                    print(error.description)
                    return
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                print("codigoCliente = ", resultadoLoginCentral[0].codigoCliente)
                print("permissoes = " , resultadoLoginCentral[0].permissoes)
                break
            default:
                break
            }




        }

        func didFailRequest(err: String, requestName: String) {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

            switch requestName {
            case nomeServico:
             return
            default:
                break
            }
        }

 func showAlert() {
        let loginAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Central do Assinante", message: "Login/Senha inválidos", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let acaoDefault = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
        loginAlert.addAction(acaoDefault)
        present(loginAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: which kind of validation you want to do?

Comment: I just need it to check if the resultadoLoginCentral has a codigoCliente and permissoes, if it does than show a new view, if not show an alert.

Comment: after `resultadoLoginCentral = try LoginCentralModel.realizarLoginCentral(results: results)` you can check with && otherwise show alert

Comment: before `catch let error as XMLParseError` or after the entire `case nomeServico:`

Comment: inside `do{` and after `resultadoLoginCentral = try LoginCentralModel.realizarLoginCentral(results: results)` this line .

Comment: Can you please give me an example,  @PiyushRathi?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130506/discussion-between-piyush-rathi-and-joe-sene).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your validation code here

```
 do{
     resultadoLoginCentral = try LoginCentralModel.realizarLoginCentral(results: results)

   //Put here code 
   // we need to call this in main thread 
     DispatchQueue.main.sync {

        if resultadoLoginCentral.codigoCliente.characters.count > 0 && resultadoLoginCentral.permissoes.characters.count > 0{{
           // Login process

       }else{
        //Show Alert
     }
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps